# Textview Stuck at Bottom of Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, textview

[image]I am having some difficulties with positioning text in landscape layouts. Whatever I do, the text seems to be stuck at the bottom. Other elements such as buttons move fine. Another weird thing is that the text moves fine in the Design editor but the position will stay the same in the emulator. Help is appreciated.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Not moving"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/fullscreen_content2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content2"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Not moving"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
                android:layout_above="@+id/floatingActionButton11"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
            app:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_light"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_forward1"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton11"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:rippleColor="#33b5e5" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you add screenshot ?

Comment: Sure, I will add them now.

Comment: Where is that `floatingActionButton11`?

Comment: I didn't include that to make the code simpler.

Comment: is that fab in some other layout?

Comment: Please include full layout details.. This is just some short of content.

Comment: Ok, I included everything.

Comment: you want you fab to bottom of your text views?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I'm trying to do, but the text is stuck. It seems to move just fine when vertical.

Comment: add this to your fab 
                android:layout_below="THE_ID_OF_LAST_TEXT_VIEW"

Comment: here it might be fullscreen_content2

Comment: let me know if it worked.

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="Not moving"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
     android:layout_above="@+id/fullscreen_content2"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
     android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content2"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:gravity="center"
     android:text="Not moving"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_marginBottom="200dp"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
     android:id="@+id/floatingActionButton11"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_marginBottom="250dp"
     app:backgroundTint="@android:color/background_light"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_action_forward1"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

     android:layout_below="@+id/fullscreen_content2"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"  

     android:clickable="true"
     app:rippleColor="#33b5e5" />
```

Comment: They are in the same relative layout.

Comment: The text is still stuck. The weird thing is that the text moves perfectly fine in the Design section as intended but the emulator is displaying a totally different layout.

Comment: I fix a mistake. Use `layout_below` in FloatingActionButton instead of `layout_above`

Comment: Thank you, this works fine! But the main problem I found was that the emulator wasn't displaying the right XML file for some reason. Very annoying!